# Has the CDC (already) published these mask recommendations that Trump has just revealed?

Tags: united-states, covid-19, reference-request, cdc

The BBC had this on their [live feed](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/live/world-52146227?pinned_post_locator=urn:asset:7b39891a-7a3c-4439-9aac-71e00a527292):

> 0:34
>
> BREAKING: Health officials advise masks, Trump won't wear one
>
> President Donald Trump has announced the Centers for Disease Control (CDC) now recommends that Americans use non-medical, cloth face coverings to help prevent the spread of the virus.
>
> "From recent studies we know that the transmission from individuals without symptoms is playing a more significant role in the spread of the virus than previously understood," Mr Trump said.
>
> "With the masks, it's going to really be a voluntary thing," he emphasised. "It's voluntary, you do not have to do it. I don't think I'm going to be doing it."
>
> He notes the CDC is not recommending the use of medical-grade masks, as those should go to health care workers.

Has the CDC (already) published these recommendations that Trump mentioned somewhere on their website?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the recommendations were released today, April 3rd, on [cdc.gov](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/prevent-getting-sick/cloth-face-cover.html).

> [...]
>
> In light of this new evidence, CDC recommends wearing cloth face
> coverings in public settings where other social distancing measures
> are difficult to maintain (e.g., grocery stores and pharmacies)
> especially in areas of significant community-based transmission.
>
> [...]
>
> The cloth face coverings recommended are not surgical masks or N-95
> respirators.  Those are critical supplies that must continue to be
> reserved for healthcare workers and other medical first responders, as
> recommended by current CDC guidance.